# How to display ONLY products which associated products are in stock with custom collection

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, collection, out-of-stock, associated-products

I'm having a hard time on how to display those configurable products which associated products are in stock only.

For example, if I have a configurable product and the quantity stock status of its associated products are out of stock, then when I create a custom product collection, that configurable product will not be displayed or will not be included in my query.

Here's my custom collection code:

```
<?php $attributeCode = 'violator_tags';                                    
 // load attribute                                                 
  $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);                   
  $categoryLink = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(146)->getUrl(); 
     //146 category ID of BestSeller                                     
     //get option id and label array                                       
  if ($attribute->usesSource()) {                                    
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);               
  }                                                                 

  $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')                    
                ->addAttributeToFilter(
                            array(
                                  array('attribute'=>$attributeCode, 'finset'=>132)
                            )
                        )
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);                       

  // show only enabled products   
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
        ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products); 

        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);                                      

 // show only visible products 
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
        ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);                 
 ?>
```

Currently, it displays the configurable products with OUT OF STOCK associated products. Did I miss something?

Using Magento 1.9 CE
Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, code is not tested

```
$attributeCode = 'violator_tags';
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());

$collection = $category->getProductCollection();

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')                    
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                      array('attribute'=>$attributeCode, 'finset'=>132)
                )
            )

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the suggestion and I tried it but it didn't work. The configurable product with OUT OF STOCK associate products is still there. When I click the configurable product, this is the result. http://prnt.sc/euy69b

Comment: I was just trying to display the products on the homepage. This is the result when I tried your suggested code. http://prnt.sc/euy70q . You can see that the configurable product is still there. It should be removed since there are NO IN STOCK associated products on it. Please help. Thanks!